Using "content" vs. "contents" when referring to multiple written works
I am aware of the previous discussions on "content" vs. "contents". According to the top answer there, it looks like they can be used interchangeably when referring to a written work (emphasis mine):

contents [plural] : 1) the things that are inside a box, bag, room etc
2) the things that are written in a letter, book etc


content [singular, uncountable]: the ideas, facts, or opinions that
are contained in a speech, piece of writing, film, programme etc.

My question is: what should be done when referring to multiple written works? For example:

The content of Chapter 1 is difficult, but the contents of Chapter 2
and Chapter 3 are easy.

Here we are referring to both single and multiple written chapters. It is not clear to me whether they should both be "content", both be "contents", or if it is correct to mix a singular and plural form as in the sentence above. Is there any grammatical rule for this situation?

The rule is rewrite anything you created that's confusing. "The content of Chapter 1 is difficult, but easy in Chapter 2 and Chapter 3." You are not referring to the insides of 2 and 3, but the quality of the material inside, the content.

@YosefBaskin that is worse.  It has the structure of a compound predicate, leaving you with "The content of Chapter 1 is difficult, but the content of Chapter 1 is easy in Chapter 2 and Chapter 3."  It's obviously not the intended meaning, but I had to read it three or four times to figure that out.

@YosefBaskin Okay, but then how does this change if I am referring to the insides, e.g. "The content of Chapter 1 is published in [Smith2007]. The contents of Chapter 2 and Chapter 3 are published in [Johnson2019]." It seems bit awkward to rewrite the sentence in this case.

I'd use "The contents of Chapter 1 are published in [Smith2007]." What is contained inside forms the contents, regardless of the adult content.

The first sense of content in Wiktionary is:


(uncountable) That which is contained.

Coordinate term: contents

So contents isn't really the plural of content in this sense.  After all, if you speak of the contents of your bag, can you refer to one item in the bag as a content?  Not really.
I would therefore write:

The content of Chapter 1 is difficult, but the content of Chapter 2 and Chapter 3 is easy.

Or perhaps

The content of Chapter 1 is difficult, but the content of chapters 2 and 3 is easy.

Or, more likely

Chapter 1 is difficult, but chapters 2 and 3 are easy.


But take this with a grain of salt.  One aspect of English that seems to be changing is some sort of breakdown in uncountability.  For example, use of the phrase their citizenships increased after the middle of the 20th century, and has increased even more sharply in the last two or three decades, but it still pales in comparison to the phrase their citizenship.
For an abstract quality that someone or something possesses, it is not necessary to consider that each individual possesses a distinct individual instance of that abstract quality.  For example, if Alice is humble or not, we can speak of her humility or boastfulness.  If the same is true of Bob, we do not speak of their humilities or boastfulnesses.
For a collective or mass noun such as content, it may not be exactly the same, but it is similar.  If I want to talk about the the color of suitcase sets, I wouldn't say *Alice's luggage is green, but Bob and Carol have black luggages.

In a comment Yosef Baskin wrote:

The rule is rewrite anything you created that's confusing. "The content in Chapter 1 is difficult, but easy in Chapter 2 and Chapter 3." You are not referring to the insides of 2 and 3, but the quality of the material inside, the content.

